# Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04, Install Windows 7 (legal copy)

Tags: boot, windows, uninstall

Alright so I bought my laptop, and I didn't realize that It had Ubuntu on it. 
Honestly I've been having a hard time with this OS. Always looking for tutos and stuff..
So I decided to Dualboot with with windows, turns out It's also a bit complicated. And seeing that I don't have much space left on my hard drive, I'd rather completely Uninstall Ubuntu and Install W7.

Can I get a step-by-step tuto please? 
Thanks! :)

Comment: There's a number of answers already for this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: We deal with Ubuntu and its derivatives. Windows is not a derivative. Thus off topic.

Comment: This question was already asked on this website [here][1]




  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Just don't do it.

**Just learn how to use Ubuntu and you will love it.** If you had used Ubuntu all your life and you addicently bought a Windows laptop, you would have been struggling with Windows too. Again: Learn how to use Ubuntu and you will love it.

**But if you don't want to learn how to use Ubuntu, you could consider installing [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org). [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org) is a version of Ubuntu that works more like Windows.** It is very easy to install. Just download it, [burn it to a DVD as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Burning_from_Ubuntu), and start up from it. Then just follow the instructions. The installation is really straightforward.

Just a few of the reasons you'll love Ubuntu/Kubuntu:

- Almost no viruses
- Windows is very expensive, Ubuntu is free
- You will get free updates, forever. If you use Windows, Microsoft will force you to pay (Most of the time more than €100!) for an upgrade in a bunch of years.
- Ubuntu is known to be faster

---

### But here is how to install Windows alongside Ubuntu:

Pretty large amount of steps, but it's not really difficult!

1. Burn a DVD with Ubuntu or Kubuntu.
2. Start from the CD/DVD. If it is an Ubuntu DVD, click the Ubuntu icon in the topleft corner and search for GParted. Then click GParted. If it is a Kubuntu DVD, click the blue icon in the downleft corner, click Applications, and search for Partition. Then click the partition manager. You will see something like this in Ubuntu:
   [image]
   And something like this in Kubuntu:
   [image]
   At the top, you can see your partitions. Select the biggest partition.
3. Click Partition > Resize/Move
4. At "New size", lower the number with the amount of MB's you want to reserve for Windows.
5. Click Resize/Move, click the green checkmark, click Apply. Wait. Click OK.
6. Shut down your computer. The DVD will automatically be ejected. When asked, remove the DVD, close the tray, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Start from the Windows 7 installation disk.
8. Choose "Install now". Then choose "Custom (advanced)". Then choose "Disk 0 Unallocated space". Then choose Next.
9. Wait until installation is finshed. Your computer will start from Windows. When Windows is installed (and has performed some post-installation operations), turn off your computer.
10. Boot from the Ubuntu or Kubuntu DVD again. Select Try Ubuntu. Connect to Wi-Fi.
11. Now we, unfortunately, *have* to use the terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. The terminal will appear. Type in these commands:

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
12. With Ubuntu, click the Ubuntu icon in the top-left corner and search for Boot Repair. With Kubuntu, click the blue icon in the down-left corner and search for Boot Repair. Click Boot Repair. You should now see something like this:
    [image]
13. Click Recommended repair and wait until it's finished.
14. Shut down your computer. The DVD will automatically be ejected. When asked, remove the DVD, close the tray, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
15. **DONE!!!** Every time you turn on your PC, you can choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7 using the arrow keys. Just use the arrow keys to select Ubuntu or Windows and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you do nothing for 10 seconds, it will automatically start Ubuntu.

Comment: I spent almost 10 years using Windows. And this sudden switch to Ubuntu is not easy. 
It's like everything I need to do needs a freaking command or a tutorial to do it.. 


Expensive or not, I already bought Windows.
But If there is a simple way to add Windows (dual boot), I'll do it. Else, nope. 
I might consider Kubuntu as a second OS (Dualboot)
Thanks!

Comment: @Zied I agree about the fact that it is very stupid that everyone uses commands instead of just using menu's (There is a way to do it without a command most of the time), I have never understood that. About the dual-boot: The Windows installer is known to partly mess up Ubuntu. It is possible however. (It is unfortunely one of the few things _requiring_ commands however) I don't have time now, but I will edit my question to include dual-boot soon. It won't be that difficult ;-)

Comment: Alright awesome!! 
I'm dling Kbuntu atm, and another file that is 2.2 GB. So I won't be able to Install W7 until tomorrow. That'll you give you some time to edit your answer :p
Oh and please since I'm a total Ubuntu newbie, can I get a step-by-step tuto pelase ? xD

Comment: Will edit in an hour...

Comment: Edited! :D Phew, that was a lot of work to type... Your question has been marked as a duplicate now, but the linked answers go about completely removing Ubuntu. Mine doesn't anymore ;)

Comment: Awesome dude. Thanks a ton! :D +100000000000000

Comment: Hey com.BOY I successfully removed Ubuntu, Installed Kubuntu and W7!!
The problem is I lost some drivers (mainly internet, bluetooth ect..) I installed them on W7 and headed to Kubuntu, and found out that I have to reinstall the same drivers on Kubuntu.
I've got the drivers on my flash drive; problem is I can't execute them (and I couldn't install Wine..)

Help!!

Comment: @Zied Drivers for Windows will never work on (K)ubuntu, not even under Wine. You have to install the (K)ubuntu versions of the drivers. Since Ubuntu came preinstalled, you should be able to find drivers on the website of your manufacturer. They should be .deb files. If there are no drivers for (K)ubuntu on the website of the manufacturer, plug in Ethernet (because wireless isn't working you say), start the Software Sources application, and go to the Additional Drivers tab. Kubuntu will search for availible drivers, and then you can install them with a few clicks.